# Error when accessing Persistant vector of object instances

Tags: nearprotocol

My Near contact contract returns an error when I attempt to access a Persistent vector of object instances in the listcourses function.

```
Log [dev-1642726071766-23690329778292]: ABORT: Cannot parse JSON, filename: "~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts" line: 144 col: 5
        Failure [dev-1642726071766-23690329778292]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: Cannot parse JSON, filename: \"~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts\" line: 144 col: 5"}}
ServerTransactionError: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: Cannot parse JSON, filename: \"~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts\" line: 144 col: 5"}}
    at Object.parseResultError (/home/jjsullivan/.nvm/versions/node/v17.2.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:31:29)
    at Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (/home/jjsullivan/.nvm/versions/node/v17.2.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:160:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async scheduleFunctionCall (/home/jjsullivan/.nvm/versions/node/v17.2.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/commands/call.js:57:38)
    at async Object.handler (/home/jjsullivan/.nvm/versions/node/v17.2.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9) {
  type: 'FunctionCallError',
```

```js
import { storage, context, PersistentVector } from "near-sdk-as";
import { Course } from "./course";

// return the string 'hello world'
export function helloWorld(): string {
    return 'hello world and \r\ngreetings earthlings from the Blockchain Academy'
}

export function welcomeUser(): string {
    return "Greetings " + context.sender + " .... :)"
}


let studentlist = new PersistentVector<string>('student');
let absentlist = new PersistentVector<string>('absent');
let roster = new PersistentVector<string>('list');
let courselist = new PersistentVector<Course>('courses');

@mutateState()
export function initial(): string{

    if(roster.length < 1 ){

        //let courselist = new PersistentVector<Course>('courses');
        let slist = new Array<string>();
        let courseqty = new Array<Course>();
        let scount: i32 = 0;
        let strstuds: string = "";
        let course0 = new Course(101, "Java", true);
        let crs: string = "";
        courselist.push(course0);
        let courseamt: i32 = 0;

        slist[0] = "Rob Sims";
        scount++;
        slist[1] = "Mike Dorgan";
        scount++;
        slist[2] = "Tom Reager";
        scount++;
        slist[3] = "Mary Smith";
        scount++;
        slist[4] = "Ryan Williams";
        scount++;
        slist[5] = "Bryant Nielson";
        scount++;
        slist[6] = "Ryan Kraz";
        scount++;
        for(let j = 0; j < scount; j++){
            studentlist.push(slist[j]);
            roster.push(slist[j]);
            const mystudent = slist[j];
            strstuds = strstuds + " " + j.toString() + ": " + mystudent + ", ";
        }
        courseamt = courselist.length;
        strstuds = strstuds + " \nThere is " + courseamt.toString() + " course.  The course is: " + course0.get_coursename();
        return strstuds;
     }else {

        return "Students may be initialized.";
    }
}

export function markabsent(studentnum: i32): string {

    if(studentlist.containsIndex(studentnum)){
            let abstudent: string = "";
            abstudent = studentlist[studentnum];
            studentlist.swap_remove(studentnum);
            absentlist.push(abstudent);
            return "Student " + abstudent + " marked absent.";
    }
    return "ok";
}

export function listabsent(): Array<string> {
    let abstudlist = new Array<string>();
    let indx = new Array<i32>();
    let i: i32 = 0;
    while (i < absentlist.length){
            indx[i] = i;
            abstudlist.push(indx[i].toString() + " : " + absentlist[i]);
            i++;
    }
    return abstudlist;

}

export function addStudent(student: string): string{

    let mystudent: string = "";
    mystudent = student;
    studentlist.push(mystudent);
    roster.push(mystudent);
    return "Student " + mystudent + " added. There are now " +      studentlist.length.toString() + " students.";

}


export function removeStudent(rmstud: string): string{

    let ablist = new Array<string>();
    let studlist = new Array<string>();
    let rmstudent: string = "";
    let abstudent: string = "";
    let stud: string = "";
    let abindx = new Array<i32>();
    let absentidx: i32;
    //let ridx = new Array<i32>();
    //let abidx = new Array<i32>();
    let x: i32 = 0;
    let y: i32 = 0;

    while (y < studentlist.length){
            //ridx[y] = y;
            stud = studentlist[y];
            if(stud == rmstud){

                    rmstudent = studentlist.swap_remove(y);
            }
            y++;
    }

    while (x < absentlist.length){

            abstudent = absentlist[x];
            if(abstudent == rmstud){

                    rmstudent = absentlist.swap_remove(x);
            }
            x++;

    }
    return "Removed " + rmstudent;
}

export function listStudents(): Array<string>{

    let studlist = new Array<string>();
    let indx = new Array<i32>();
    let i: i32 = 0;
    //
    while (i < studentlist.length){
            indx[i] = i;
            studlist.push(indx[i].toString() + " : " + studentlist[i]);
            i++;
    }
    return studlist;
}

export function movePresent(abstudnum: i32): string {

    if(absentlist.containsIndex(abstudnum)){

            let abstudent: string = "";
            abstudent = absentlist[abstudnum];
            absentlist.swap_remove(abstudnum);
            studentlist.push(abstudent);
            return "Student " + abstudent + " moved from absent tp present.";
    }else {
            return "Cannot find student with index " + abstudnum.toString() + ".";
    }

}

export function addCourse(id: i32, cnm: string, offered: boolean): string{

    let id0: i32 = 0;
    let cnm0: string = "";
    let offered0: boolean;
    let clist: string = "";

    id0 = id;
    cnm0 = cnm;
    offered0 = offered;

    let len: i32 = 0;
    len = courselist.length;
    let newcourse = new Course(id0, cnm0, offered0);
    courselist.push(newcourse);
    len = courselist.length;

    let addedcourse: string = "";
    let courseid: i32 = 0;
    let mycrs_name: string = "";
    let noffered: boolean;

    courseid = newcourse.get_coursenum();
    mycrs_name = newcourse.get_coursename();
    noffered = newcourse.get_offered();

    //const thecourse = courselist[id];

    addedcourse = "Added course. ID: " + courseid.toString() + " Name: " + newcourse.get_coursename() + " Offered: " + noffered.toString();
    addedcourse = addedcourse + ". The course list length: " + len.toString();

    return addedcourse;
}

@mutateState()
export function listcourses(): string{

    let clist = new Array<Course>();
    let z: i32 = 0;
    let coursedata: string = "";
    let myid: i32 = 0;
    let mycname: string = "";
    let myoffered: boolean;
    //let courseinfo: Course;

    while (z < courselist.length){

            clist.push(courselist[z]);
            coursedata = coursedata + " " + myid.toString() + " "+ mycname;
            z++;
    }
    return coursedata + " " + z.toString();

}
```

Class code

```as
//@nearBindgen
export class Course {

    private coursenum: i32
    private cname: string;
    private offered: boolean;

    constructor (coursenum: i32, cname: string, offered: boolean) {
        
        this.cname = cname;
        this.coursenum = coursenum;
        this.offered = offered;

    }

    set_coursenum(): void {
        this.coursenum = coursenum;
    }

    set_coursename(): void {

        this.cname = cname;
    }

    set_offered(): void {
        this.offered = true;
    }

    set_notoffered(): void {
        this.offered = false;

    }

    get_coursenum(): i32 {
        return this.coursenum;
    }

    get_coursename(): string {
        return  this.cname;
    }

    get_offered(): boolean {
        return this.offered;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the `@nearBindgen` annotation in your class.
It looks like it's commented out in the top of your class code. Remove the first two slashes "//" before `// @nearBindgen`.

That way, you're able to serialize and deserialize the class to and from JSON

```as
@nearBindgen  // remove the "//"
export class Course {
...
}
```